# Find out Object type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to debug some JQuery `ajaxSetUp` behaviour. I set a timeout value and wish to see it set in the debugger. To do this I need to know what to watch while debugging.  To investigate where the timeout is set, I do the following in a firefox console:

```
var obj = jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 120000
});
console.log("obj=" + obj.timeout)
```

I want to find out what type of object `obj` is?  I know JavaScript is dynamically typed but if I can find out what object it is then I know what to add a watch to when debugging.

Comment: You want to know that obj is really an object from ajax Setup? Not going to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Type of `obj` is `object`. See:

```
typeof obj
// "object"
```

Also, the constructor is global javascript `Object`. Here:

```
obj.constructor.name
// "Object"
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a few [utility methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/) like `.isArray()`, `.isFunction()`, `.isNumeric()` and `.isPlainObject()` that return true or false. Use these one after the other to determine whether an object is of a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 1):

there is special function in jquery

```
jQuery.type(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't a good approach for this problem.  I looked at the JQuery source and saw when you invoke ajaxSetUp it updates the jQuery.ajaxSettings object.

So if you do...

```
console.log(jQuery.ajaxSettings.timeout)
```

in the debug console you'll get the value.

I am putting answer here in case it is use to anyone.